# input.readLine waiting (blocked) for ever, how to deal with this?

Tags: android, gradle, inputstream, bufferedreader, readline

I have a Java server that it is compiling Android APKs by command line and writing the output into a file, this is the source code:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("gradlew assembleRelease", null , new File(this.workDir));            
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String line = null;     
        while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
            standardOutput.writeln(line);
        }
        input.close();
```

It is working perfect with all the Android projects but if the android project has a directory or a file with rare characters (á, ñ...) inside assets folder, then, gets stuck in `line = input.readLine()`

I opened jconsole to see where is being stuck and i got this:

```
Name: Thread-3
State: RUNNABLE
Total blocked: 0  Total waited: 6
Stack trace: 
java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method)
java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:255)
java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:284)
java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
   - locked java.io.BufferedInputStream@e70e4f8
sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
   - locked java.io.InputStreamReader@4426351b
java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:161)
java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:324)
   - locked java.io.InputStreamReader@4426351b
java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:389)
com.mobinGen.jobs.AndroidJob.releaseCompile(AndroidJob.java:329)
com.mobinGen.jobs.AndroidJob.jobProcess(AndroidJob.java:122)
com.mobinGen.jobs.BaseJob.process(BaseJob.java:138)
com.mobinGen.generationAPI.GeneratorAndroid$AndroidJobsAsker.run(GeneratorAndroid.java:230)
```

As you can see it is blocked in line 329, which is `while ((line = input.readLine()) != null)`

How can I deal with this? it is a huge problem because the server is being waiting for ever without compiling the next coming Android projects.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, are you sure you want to read from `p.getInputStream()`? The gradle process will be writing to `p.getOutputStream()` or `p.getErrorStream()`

Secondly, I think you should use the [tooling api](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/embedding.html) to invoke gradle instead of using `Runtime` (See [GradleConnector](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/tooling/GradleConnector.html))

Comment: I need to do this without gradleconnector. BTW are you sure about outputstream? in the documentation of inputstream i can read this: Returns the input stream connected to the normal output of the subprocess. The stream obtains data piped from the standard output of the process represented by this Process object.

Comment: how to get gradle output from outputstream?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want to use an explicit charset in the InputStreamReader.

See [InputStreamReader(InputStream in, Charset cs)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html#InputStreamReader(java.io.InputStream,%20java.nio.charset.Charset))